# Grails Ajax rendering list action

Tags: ajax, jquery, grails, grails-2.0

Trying to render all the **Contacts** using ajax ([This is a snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1ZCI.png))

So on click, it will list the contacts in a `div` on the update action. I have tested with a basic date function (*see commented out render action Controller*)  to make sure ajax part could work and that does, but handling the list I have hit a wall with and going round in circles

*GSP*:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="event" action="showContacts" update="divContactList">Show Contacts!</g:remoteLink>

<div id="divContactList">Show contacts Here...
    <g:each in="${contactList}" status = "i" var="contact">
       <p>${contact.forname}</p>            
       <p>${contact.email}</p>
    </g:each>
</div>
```

*Controller*:

```
def showContacts = {
    def contactList = Contact.findAllByUser(lookupPerson())
//        render "The time is now ${new Date()}"
    render([contactList: contactList])        
}
```

So overall it's not showing anything from the contactList in the web page, help on this would be appreciated

Comment: **UPDATE** [link](http://d.pr/i/mEXv) 

This kind of works... however, I am not quite doing something right (please refer to screenshot thank you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

_templateName.gsp:

```
<g:each in="${contactList}" status = "i" var="contact">
       <p>${contact.forname}</p>            
       <p>${contact.email}</p>
    </g:each>
```

GSP:

```
<g:remoteLink controller="event" action="showContacts" update="divContactList">Show Contacts!</g:remoteLink>

<div id="divContactList">Show contacts Here...
    <g:render template="layouts/templateName" model="[contactList: contactList]" />
</div>
```

Controller:

```
def showContacts = {
    def contactList = Contact.findAllByUser(lookupPerson())
//        render "The time is now ${new Date()}"
    render(template: 'layouts/templateName', model:[contactList: contactList])        
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for the response James, great little solution! I have spent countless hours messing around. I have learned a great deal from the both of you.

Answer (score 3):

Clicking the remote link will send an AJAX call to the *showContacts* action, get an HTML answer and [update](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#updatingContent) the content of *divContactList* with the returned answer.
The *showContacts* action will render a template with the same name, passing it the contactList as part of the model.
If you would like the AJAX call to render the list of contacts you can try one of the following [options](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#ajaxOnTheServer):

1. Content Centric Ajax - Have the *showContacts* action render a template which displays the list of contacts
2. Data Centric Ajax - Have the *showContacts* action send a JSON/XML response representing the list of contacts and have a client side JavaScript code render this JSON/XML as the contact list

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply !

That's interesting, one thing little confused about on the doc, on there example on the website with the data centric option it updates to "foo" but there is nothing on there html wise with that... could you tell me please it's purpose in that scenario  ?

Comment: This example is showing how to update the content using a JavaScript method. Not sure why it contains the "foo" update, since the update attribute is optional